# Kubernetes sporadic DNS error EAI_AGAIN with NodeJS pods

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, dns, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

We are in the process of transitioning from a self-managed kubernetes cluster to Google's GKE Autopilot. All of our incoming API requests are handled by an "API Gateway" server that routes requests to various internal services. When testing this API Gateway on the new GKE Autopilot cluster, we noticed sporadic `EAI_AGAIN` DNS resolution errors for the internal services.

These errors occur even at low load (50-100 requests per second), but appear to increase when the number of concurrent requests increases. They also occur when rolling out a new image to downstream pods, despite having multiple replicas and a rolling update strategy.

Our API Gateway is written in NodeJS. Researching online ([1](https://tech.findmypast.com/k8s-dns-lookup/), [2](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15780)), I found that the issue might be related to one of (i) overloading the kubernetes-internal DNS server, (ii) overloading the nodejs event loop since `getaddrinfo` is blocking, (iii) an issue with MUSL in alpine-based NodeJS images, or (iv) a race condition in earlier linux kernel versions.

All but (iv) can probably be ruled out in our case:

- (i) `kubedns` is at very low CPU usage, and GKE Autopilot implements node-local DNS caching by default.
- (ii) Our API Gateway is at low CPU usage. The event loop does appear to lag sporadically for up to 100ms, but there is not an overwhelming correlation to the `EAI_AGAIN` error rate.
- (iii) We are running debian-based NodeJS images.
- (iv) I'm not sure what linux kernel version GKE Autopilot pods are running on, but at our low load I don't think we should be hitting this error.

It is strange to me that we are seeing these errors given that our load is not high compared to what other companies are running on kubernetes. Does someone have any pointers for where to look further?

Comment: in GKE kube-dns is configured to handle 1500 max connection per pod. I assume in your case you have 2 replicas ? Is it possible that your API Gateway is issuing a lot of connections to kube-dns ?

Comment: Yes, we have to replicas of `kube-dns`. I don't think we're hitting the limit; the error occurs even with only 16 concurrent requests to the API Gateway, and the gateway should only perform a single DNS lookup per request.

Comment: It's very hard to help out with this issue. My best advice would be to get in touch with support and try GKE in Standard mode to see if that will help. In Standard mode you can force kube-dns to scale out to see if that improves the situation. Or Use Cloud DNS for GKE https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cloud-dns

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue? I have almost identical situation.